# How do I move from one ViewController (containing a custom UIView) to another ViewController (containing a UITableView) on click?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, storyboard

**NOTE:** I understand, similar questions have been asked many times here at stackoverflow, but I could not solve the problem I'm facing. So please don't mark this question as "already asked" or so.

Actually I've two ViewControllers, CalendarViewController and a FruitsListViewController.

The CalendarViewController contains MyCalendarView (subclass of UIView) to display the calendar, while FruitsListViewController contains UITableView to display the list of fruits.

When I click in the certain region of MyCalendarView within the CalendarViewController, it extracts the corresponding date and prints to the log.

**Question:**

I want to achieve that when I click on the certain place of the MyCalendarView of the CalendarViewController, I'm brought to the FruitsListViewController. But I'm not able to drag the segue from that MyCalendarView to the FruitsListViewController (in fact only able to drag from that MyCalendarView to its parent view and nothing elsewhere).

Kindly guide me how can I achieve this?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your should override `prepareForSegue` from CalendarViewController class and call the  `prepareForSegue(::)` from some `clickCertainPlaceOfTheCustomUIView()`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let destView = segue.destinationViewController as! FruitsListViewController
        destView.chosenFruitsArray = self.myFruitsArray
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. 
1- Xcode does not recognise the SubjectViewController, what should I write in place of it? By the way if I replace it with FruitsListViewController, the error disappears.
2- What is meant by destView.chosenFruitsArray = self.myFruitsArray ?

Comment: @FarazAhmad sorry, you don't need to specify type here, I've edited post.
destView.chosenFruitsArray = self.myFruitsArray  // here is array of fruits (property of FruitsListViewController), so after executing this function the FruitsListViewController will get the array from CalendarViewController

Answer (score 0):

Drag segue from first ViewController to the other ViewController.

on ta, call `performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueIdentifier", sender: nil)` and in `prepareForSegue` customize what data should be sent to the other ViewController.